# how to combine web adress with string value in hyperlink google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

could someone help with how to properly combine string value from variable with text chain to create the desired hyperlink?

I am getting error message probably because the ' ' and ""are not used the right way.
I also dunno if the + sign or the & should be used.

```
    var sheet = sss22.getSheetByName('Otevrene zakazky');
    var cislo = sheet.getRange(1, 1).getValue().toString();
    var refSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(cislo);
    var refSheetId = refSheet.getSheetId().toString(); //string value (ID number of the sheet)
    var source987 = sht.getRange(sht.getLastRow(), 1)
    var source2222 = source987.setValue('=hyperlink("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/2M_Q1q2ElA29bRmwp2-MKQDciv2W3zs/edit#gid=' + refSheetId"), "Detail Zakázky")');
```

Thank you in advance,
Matt

[image: Code screenshot]

Comment: 1) You should use setFormula() instead of setValue 2) Use '+' (the concatenation operator) to add your sheet id to your string.  range.setFormula("hyperlink('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/2M_Q1q2ElA29bRmwp2-MKQDciv2W3zs/edit#gid=" + refSheetId + ", 'Detail Zakázky')");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the second `+` and opening `'`. You also don't need the closing parenthesis that you wrote here `refSheetId")`.

This should be your final line:

```
var source2222 = source987.setValue('=hyperlink("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/2M_Q1q2ElA29bRmwp2-MKQDciv2W3zs/edit#gid=' + refSheetId + '", "Detail Zakázky")');
```